# Android 11 memory crash

Tags: c#, android, amazon-web-services, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am an indie game developer and i am deperately stuck in a bug please help me >_<

I build my mobile game in Unity

1. My game will send a request and download some image from the server on start up.
2. The image will be stored in local and be displayed in the mainmenu. However, after several requests, the app just crash and closed itself.

I've test it on different Android Version and this problem only occurs on Android 11. I've also try to queue up and delay each request to avoid overloading the memory but it doesn't help.

I'm really fustrated by this, can anyone help?

Heres the error log and code:
code:

```
public async Task<Sprite> LoadSprite (string url, string relativeFilePath)
        {
            //queue up job
            int selfJobID = totalJobCount;
            totalJobCount++;

            await HaltLoadSprite(selfJobID);
            byte[] dataArray = await Load(url, relativeFilePath);
            Debug.Log("doing load sprite job: " + selfJobID);

            var texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            if (dataArray != null && dataArray.Length > 0)
            {
                texture.LoadImage(dataArray);
                texture.Apply();
            }

            Sprite returnSprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * .5f);


            await Task.Delay(3000);
            SceneController.instance.UpdateJobProgress(newJobID, 1f);   //loading screen

            currentProcessingJobID++;   //processed job

            return returnSprite;
        }

async Task<int> HaltLoadSprite(int selfJobID)
        {
            while (selfJobID != currentProcessingJobID)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            return 0;
        }

protected async Task<byte[]> Load(string url, string relativeFilePath)
        {
            UnityWebRequest request = null;
            byte[] rtByte = new byte[] {};
            
            try
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, relativeFilePath);

                // Check local disk first.
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    rtByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                }
                // Try to download the story from file server.
                else
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
                        throw new Exception($"Download link is blank or with white space: {url}");

                    request = new UnityWebRequest(url);
                    request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
                    await request.SendWebRequest();
                    while (!request.isDone)
                    {
                        float progress = request.downloadProgress;
                        await Task.Yield();
                    }

                    // Wait for 1 frame to prevent error occurr when the file being loaded immediately.
                    await Task.Yield();
                    Debug.Log($"Download progress: {request.downloadProgress * 100}%");

                    // Error checking.
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.error))
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Error occurred while downloading story: {request.error}");
                    }

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.downloadHandler.text))
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Error occurred after download the story: empty return.");
                    }

                    // Create the folder if not existed.
                    string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

                    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
                    }

                    // Save the text into file.
                    File.WriteAllBytes(path, request.downloadHandler.data);

                    rtByte = request.downloadHandler.data;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogError(e.Message);
            }

            request?.Dispose();
            request = null;

            return rtByte;
        }
```

Error log:

```
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021-12-28 14:43:37.428 17643-18145/? I/Unity: doing load sprite job: 2
Zoomob.Utility.FileSystem:.ctor()
System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
System.Action:Invoke()
System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunCallback(ContextCallback, Object, Task&)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult(TResult)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1:Create()
Zoomob.Utility.FileSystem:.ctor()
System.Threading.ContextCallback:Invoke(Object)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MoveNextRunner:Run()
System.Action:Invoke()
System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback:Invoke(Object)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:Exec()
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:Exec()

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH: pid: 17643, tid: 18183, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> sensation.chooseyourstory.romance <<<
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #00 pc 00000000001db2f4  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #01 pc 00000000001e0e48  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #02 pc 00000000001e0ba4  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #03 pc 00000000001da9c8  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #04 pc 00000000001da984  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #05 pc 00000000000d1d50  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #06 pc 00000000003cfe58  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #07 pc 00000000007ba038  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #08 pc 00000000007bf9c0  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #09 pc 00000000007b6e78  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:42.702 17643-18183/? E/CRASH:       #10 pc 00000000002f7d9c  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
2021-12-28 14:43:52.057 17643-17643/? I/ViewRootImpl@9e11917[UnityPlayerActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2021-12-28 14:43:52.058 17643-17643/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** 
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2019.3.15f1 (59ff3e03856d)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/r8qzhx/r8q:11/RP1A.200720.012/G7810ZHS3CUJ2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '6'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-12-28 14:43:42+0800
pid: 17643, tid: 18183, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> sensation.chooseyourstory.romance <<<
uid: 10325
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7c5b442fa0
    x0  0000007c5b242f60  x1  b400007b80dc1510  x2  0000000000000007  x3  0000000000000000
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000102
    x8  0000007c5b442f60  x9  0000000000000018  x10 0000000000003238  x11 b400007c51f1d524
    x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000058  x14 0000000000000001  x15 0000000000000000
    x16 0000007c5b223648  x17 0000007d5aff9bc8  x18 0000007bd63848a0  x19 0000007c5b24f7c0
    x20 b400007b80dc1510  x21 0000000000000007  x22 0000000000000007  x23 0000007c5b240606
    x24 0000000000000018  x25 0000000000003234  x26 0000000000003238  x27 ffffff6100000000
    x28 0000000000002a10  x29 000000000000000b
    sp  0000007bd6384790  lr  0000007c5a471e4c  pc  0000007c5a46c2f4
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000001db2f4  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #01 pc 00000000001e0e48  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #02 pc 00000000001e0ba4  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #03 pc 00000000001da9c8  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #04 pc 00000000001da984  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #05 pc 00000000000d1d50  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #06 pc 00000000003cfe58  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #07 pc 00000000007ba038  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #08 pc 00000000007bf9c0  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #09 pc 00000000007b6e78  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #10 pc 00000000002f7d9c  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #11 pc 00000000000f41b4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 72bf79ff636decb4f24a88c1b61c3063)
      #12 pc 000000000008ede4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 72bf79ff636decb4f24a88c1b61c3063)

    at libunity.0x1db2f4(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1e0e48(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1e0ba4(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1da9c8(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1da984(Native Method)
    at libunity.0xd1d50(Native Method)
2021-12-28 14:43:52.058 17643-17643/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at libunity.0x3cfe58(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x7ba038(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x7bf9c0(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x7b6e78(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2f7d9c(Native Method)
    at libc.__pthread_start(void*)(__pthread_start:64)
    at libc.__start_thread(__start_thread:64)
2021-12-28 14:43:52.058 17643-17643/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: sensation.chooseyourstory.romance, PID: 17643
java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2019.3.15f1 (59ff3e03856d)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/r8qzhx/r8q:11/RP1A.200720.012/G7810ZHS3CUJ2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '6'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-12-28 14:43:42+0800
pid: 17643, tid: 18183, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> sensation.chooseyourstory.romance <<<
uid: 10325
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7c5b442fa0
    x0  0000007c5b242f60  x1  b400007b80dc1510  x2  0000000000000007  x3  0000000000000000
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000102
    x8  0000007c5b442f60  x9  0000000000000018  x10 0000000000003238  x11 b400007c51f1d524
    x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000058  x14 0000000000000001  x15 0000000000000000
    x16 0000007c5b223648  x17 0000007d5aff9bc8  x18 0000007bd63848a0  x19 0000007c5b24f7c0
    x20 b400007b80dc1510  x21 0000000000000007  x22 0000000000000007  x23 0000007c5b240606
    x24 0000000000000018  x25 0000000000003234  x26 0000000000003238  x27 ffffff6100000000
    x28 0000000000002a10  x29 000000000000000b
    sp  0000007bd6384790  lr  0000007c5a471e4c  pc  0000007c5a46c2f4

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000001db2f4  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #01 pc 00000000001e0e48  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #02 pc 00000000001e0ba4  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #03 pc 00000000001da9c8  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #04 pc 00000000001da984  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #05 pc 00000000000d1d50  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #06 pc 00000000003cfe58  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #07 pc 00000000007ba038  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #08 pc 00000000007bf9c0  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #09 pc 00000000007b6e78  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #10 pc 00000000002f7d9c  /data/app/~~iWkSRq_iYcstQRB-RcEx9w==/sensation.chooseyourstory.romance-Gsv5aBlUnRrTsbc439mt7g==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c6a538f20b942bc471ed67e90c26a0ba848cd887)
      #11 pc 00000000000f41b4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 72bf79ff636decb4f24a88c1b61c3063)
      #12 pc 000000000008ede4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 72bf79ff636decb4f24a88c1b61c3063)

    at libunity.0x1db2f4(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1e0e48(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1e0ba4(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1da9c8(Native Method)
2021-12-28 14:43:52.058 17643-17643/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at libunity.0x1da984(Native Method)
    at libunity.0xd1d50(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x3cfe58(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x7ba038(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x7bf9c0(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x7b6e78(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2f7d9c(Native Method)
    at libc.__pthread_start(void*)(__pthread_start:64)
    at libc.__start_thread(__start_thread:64)
```

Comment: I know nothing about unity but it seems it happens with the second picture, maybe the picture it self is just too big? Maybe try removing that specific picture and see if it's happening with other pictures also?

Comment: This error occurs in different places, it isn't always the second picture...

Comment: I see. Well, final question that might also help, I see in load function you are printing debug message that is not shown. Did you make sure no image is too big?

Comment: hmm...not so sure, but i know the images stored on the server is in png format, ~0.5-2MB

Comment: 2MB might be bit problematic. I'd start by first decreasing the number of pictures to say, 5, "lightest" ones, just to start diagnosing the error

Comment: I may try that later. One interesting thing is, this code works perfectly fine on older Android version like 7 & 8. And on Android 11, it only works occasionally...